# How to properly escape filenames in Windows cmd.exe?

Tags: cmd, escaping, filenames

If you have a filename containing spaces, you typically double quote it on the Windows command shell (`cmd.exe`).

```
dir "\Program Files"
```

This also works for other special characters like `^&;,=`. But it doesn't work for percent signs as they may be part of variable substitution. For example,

```
mkdir "%os%"
```

will create a directory named `Windows_NT`. To escape the percent sign, a caret can be used:

```
mkdir ^%os^%
```

But unfortunately, the caret sign loses its meaning in double quotes:

```
mkdir "^%os^%"
```

creates a directory named `^%os^%`.

This is what I found out so far (Windows 7 command shell):

- The characters `^` and `&` can be escaped with either a caret or double quotes.
- The characters `;`, `,`, `=`, and space can only be escaped with double quotes.
- The character `%` can only be escaped with a caret.
- The characters `` '`+-~_.!#$@()[]{} `` apparently don't have to be escaped in filenames.
- The characters `<>:"/\|?*` are illegal in filenames anyway.

This seems to make a general algorithm to quote filenames rather complicated. For example, to create a directory named `My favorite %OS%`, you have to write:

```
mkdir "My favorite "^%OS^%
```

Question 1: Is there an easier way to safely quote space and percent characters?

Question 2: Are the characters `` '`+-~_.!#$@()[]{} `` really safe to use without escaping?

Comment: Hmm. `mkdir "My favorite %OS%"` works expected ... you don't need to escape the `%` with `^`

Comment: @DavidPostill It doesn't work for me on Windows 7. What Windows version do you use? Is the `%OS%` variable set? What does `echo %OS%` print?

Comment: Windows 7, `%OS%` is set. Output from `echo %OS%` is `Windows_NT`

Comment: @DavidPostill To clarify: I expect a directory named `My favorite %OS%` without variable substitution. When I run `mkdir "My favorite %OS%"`, I get a directory named `My favorite Windows_NT` which is not what I want.

Comment: `mkdir "My favorite %%OS%%"` works (with the second `"` at the end where it should be).

Comment: Detailed answer provided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The characters `^` and `&` can be escaped with either a caret or double quotes.

There is an additional restriction when piping.

> When a pipe is used, the expressions are parsed twice. First when the
>   expression before the pipe is executed and a second time when the
>   expression after the pipe is executed. **So to escape any characters in
>   the second expression double escaping is needed**:
>
> The line below will echo a single `&` character:
>
> ```
> break| echo ^^^&
> ```

---

#### The character `%` can only be escaped with a caret.

`%` can also be escaped by doubling it.

> The `%` character has a special meaning for command line parameters
>   and `FOR` parameters.
>
> To treat a percent as a regular character, double it:
>
> `%%`

---

#### For example, to create a directory named My favorite %OS%, you have to write:

> ```
> mkdir "My favorite "^%OS^%
> ```
>
> Question 1: Is there an easier way to safely quote space and percent
>   characters?

Use `%%` instead of `%` with the second `"` at the end where you would normally expect it to be.

```
C:\test\sub>dir
...

 Directory of C:\test\sub

03/06/2015  14:40    <DIR>          .
03/06/2015  14:40    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  82,207,772,672 bytes free

C:\test\sub>mkdir "My favorite %%OS%%"

C:\test\sub>dir
...
 Directory of C:\test\sub

03/06/2015  14:40    <DIR>          .
03/06/2015  14:40    <DIR>          ..
03/06/2015  14:40    <DIR>          My favorite %Windows_NT%
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  82,207,772,672 bytes free
```

> Question 2: Are the characters '`+-~_.!#$@()[]{} really safe to use without escaping?

No, again there are some additional circumstances when some of these must be escaped, for example when using delayed variable expansion or when using `for /f`.

See [Escape Characters](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) for all the details ... in particular the Summary table.

---

Sources [Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) and [Escape Characters](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php).

---

#### Further Reading

- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts?lq=1)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/1956010). What confused me is that `%%` can be used to escape `%` in batch files, but not on the command line.